# How to configure edit permissions for Panel panes?

Tags: 7, panels, users

Is there a way to configure edit (not view) permissions for a Panels 'pane'?

I would like to add a pane for 'custom content', for example above and below a view, so that the content manager role that I've setup can edit that part of the page. Seems really simple (and essential), but haven't found anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

That blog post doesn't seem to have been followed up on.  There is some discussion here regarding more granular permissions for Panels IPE:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1821618#comment-9502245

I mention it would be great to be able to change role permissions for an individual pane such as 'Move', 'Edit', 'Change Style'.

Comment: In terms of panel panes permissions when using the Panels in place editor (IPE). There is work being done in the following issues:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2151943#comment-9502417
https://www.drupal.org/node/1699432#comment-9502413

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Panels IPE: The Future](http://www.angrydonuts.com/panels-ipe-the-future).

> This feature allows users to designate Panels of various types as
>   editable in-place. This means that users with privileges are given a
>   button at the bottom of the page which allows them to dynamically add,
>   remove and rearrange content on that page. It's much more limited than
>   the typical back end editor, but is much more usable by content
>   managers who are focusing highly on the content.